# Xslt sorting nested nodes before parent by custom string values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DriverRights>
<STAFF>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>123456789</StaffID>
<Type>Lorry ABC</Type>
</EmpDetails>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>123456789</StaffID>
<Type>Jeep</Type>
</EmpDetails>
</STAFF>
</DriverRights>
<DriverRights>
<STAFF>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>7899878887</StaffID>
<Type>Lorry ABC</Type>
</EmpDetails>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>7899878887</StaffID>
<Type>SUV IX</Type>
</EmpDetails>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>7899878887</StaffID>
<Type>Jeep</Type>
</EmpDetails>
</STAFF>
</DriverRights>
<DriverRights>
<STAFF>
<EmpDetails>
<StaffID>5432101235</StaffID>
<Category>Jeep</Category>
</EmpDetails>
</STAFF>
</DriverRights>
```

---

I’m trying to get to sort the way I want it too…I’d like to sort by Lorry ABC, SUV IX and then Jeep…I was using

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending"
     select="((STAFF/EmpDetails/Type='Lorry ABC') * 1)+ 
     ((STAFF/EmpDetails/Type=='SUV IX') * 2)+ 
     ((STAFF/EmpDetails/Type=='Jeep') * 3)"/>
```

But I realised it didn’t seem to sort properly where a staffID had multiple types. So I was trying to see if I could sort the child notes first and then use my `<xsl:sort>` above?

But I'm new to xslt, and have being trying to figure it unsuccessfully -  any suggestions would be appreciated…

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Please explain which nodes are being sorted. "*sorting nested nodes before parent*" does not mean anything. And what is the correct result in the case "*where a staffID had multiple types.*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want to do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="DriverRights">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"
              select="4*(STAFF/EmpDetails/Type='Lorry ABC') 
              + 2*(STAFF/EmpDetails/Type='SUV IX') 
              + (STAFF/EmpDetails/Type='Jeep')"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: "*i dont get the numbering 4* and 2*...*" Well, they say that there are 10 types of people in this world: those who understand **binary** and those who don't.

Comment: yes yes...i just though having each (as i did) 1,2,3...etc...would be enough to set the text value as a number weight, so any number would do as long as (in this case) ... they number reduces ie . 4,2,1,0,-2...etc..

Comment: The maximum points a driver **not** licensed for 'Lorry ABC' can get is 3 (2 for SUV and 1 for Jeep). Therefore, the next factor must be 4. Similarly, the maximum points a driver can get under the current arrangement is 7 (4 + 2 + 1), so the next factor would have to be 8, etc.